# searching a certain character in strings

Tags: image, matlab

I am writing a function for remote sensing purposes  using matlab
the user will enter a folder containing 7 files into the program each file is a band of an image and the names of them is:
"b1.dat"
"b2.dat"
"b3.dat"
"b4.dat"
"b5.dat"
"b6.dat"
"b7.dat"
for example if 2 is entered as the argument of the function it will search in seven file names that are in the access and then will show b2.dat
how do you suggest me to write the code

Comment: Can you give a short example program?

Comment: The question is very vague. As it is why not use q='2'; dir(['\*' q '\*.\*']) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [uigetfiles](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22805-uigetfiles) to select the directory and `dir` to get a list of the folders contents. Once you have the list, `strfind` will tell you a file contains a given number.

Or, using uigetdir:

```
dirName =  uigetdir('C:\', 'select a directory');
contents = dir(dirName);

for c = contents
    name = c.name;
    if strfind(name,'3')
         fileToOpen = name{1};
    end
end
```

Comment: In this release we don't have uigetfiles as a function instead I used uigetdir

Comment: uigetfiles is a user supplied function that you can download.  Look at the link. I've updated my answer to work for uigetdir.

Answer (score 0):

I used these two lines of codes:
    folder = uigetdir('D:\','Select the folder containing bands')
    filenames = dir(folder)
the first line returns the path to the folder as I expected:
    folder =

D:\RS\911130 TM bands
but the second line not. I have 7 files in my folder and it returns a 9x1 struct
    filenames =

9x1 struct array with fields:
    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
for example the contents of the filenames(1,1) is:
[image]